# Windows Azure Service Bus - BrokeredMessage.Properties with Enum Value

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to add a custom property to the `BrokeredMessage.Properties` collection before sending it to the Azure Service Bus. The custom property type is an enum:

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public enum FooBar
{
    [EnumMember]
    Foo = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Bar = 1
}
```

I have also tried numerous combinations of the Attributes, and a version with no Attributes.

This is the code which adds the property and sends the message:

```
var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(new MessageObject(){ //etc });
brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("FooBar", FooBar.Foo);
queueClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
```

The following error is returned when attempting to send the message:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type Namespace.FooBar.
```

I've tried to track down some more detailed documentation on the `BrokeredMessage.Properties` limitations (if any), and can't find anything which specifies that only primitive types can be used.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Edit:

Should have said I am using V2.1.0.0 of Microsoft.ServiceBus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shortly, you can use only simple types like string, integers.

For your case, you can try two ways

1. brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("FooBar", (int)FooBar.Foo);
2. brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("FooBar", FooBar.Foo.ToString());

Choose by you self, which one is better for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This became clear, although there seems to be a lack of documentation about it (unless someone can point me in its direction?) I always prefer converting enum values to int rather than a string - so that's the option I went with.